# Extract table from Google BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to extract an existing BigQuery table to a Cloud Storage bucket using Apps Script because I need to schedule it for frequent runs. The Cloud set up (billing, api enabled) is complete and when I extract the table via the Web UI it all works fine.

Please help me with the Apps Script code. Below you can see what I am writing. It works with no error messages but it does not create the json file in Storage.

```
function SQLTest() {

var projectId = 'xx_my_project';
var datasetId = 'xx_my_dataset';      
var tableId = 'xx_my_table';   
var destinationUris = 'gs://my_bucket/my_file.json';
var destinationFormat = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON';


var job = {            
  configuration: {

extract: {
  sourceTable: {
    projectId: projectId,
    datasetId: datasetId,
    tableId: tableId
  }
  ,
 destinationUris: [destinationUris],
 destinationFormat: destinationFormat

}  
} 
}
} ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full corrected script

```
function SQLTest() {

var projectId = 'xx_my_project';
var datasetId = 'xx_my_dataset';      
var tableId = 'xx_my_table';   
var destinationUris = 'gs://my_bucket/my_file.json';
var destinationFormat = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON';          
var job = {            
configuration: {

extract: {
  sourceTable: {
    projectId: projectId,
    datasetId: datasetId,
    tableId: tableId
  }
  ,
 destinationUris: [destinationUris],

  destinationFormat: destinationFormat

}  
}
};

var request = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job,projectId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you didn't invoke any API here.

Please follow this guide on how to call a Bigquery API from Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Please also follow this guide to extract table:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert

Comment: Also, have a look at the blog post i wrote about this (change from query to extract): https://shinesolutions.com/2017/11/01/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: Thank you for this. I have followed both BQ guides you suggested and I cannot see what I missing.

Comment: Like YY said, you haven't actually invoked the API! Compare your code to the other examples closely, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);

Above is the API call, it sends a request over the network to the Bigquery servers.

In your code, you only defined some data structures, without any server interactions.

Comment: @GrahamPolley and YY, thank you very much for the direction you gave me. The actual API call for "EXTRACT" uses jobs.insert and the format it var request = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job,projectId);

Comment: @GrahamPolley, correct. This is what you made me realise I was missing after your comments. Thank you